# Where can I find the original CSS file(s) of StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, design

I know that I can use some kind of 'css beautifier' to unminify the minified css in the source of StackOverflow. But they miss what would be invaluable to me — comments (for browser-specific fixes, etc).

It would be great if some knows how to access the original CSS files used by StackOverflow, and can share the links. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder what sorts of angry rambling comments Nick has put into the various source files.

Comment: Is this really a bad thing to ask? Why would someone downvote this question?

Comment: Downvotes are weird on meta.  Even weirder on support questions like this.  I just upvoted, but I suspect a lot more downvotes are on the way

Comment: Access to these files is...uuhhh...difficult...they let Trogdor sleep in front of the safe.

Comment: I have no idea how the team feels about releasing CSS files, but I will point out that the Stack Exchange software generally is __not__ open source.

Comment: @Popular - and somewhere Richard Stallman just shed a tear

Comment: [The unminified JavaScript files are available from the `dev.` subdomain](http://dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/stub.js), but it doesn't look the the original CSS is. I wonder if the source language isn't CSS, but something like SASS or LESS.

Comment: @JeremyBanks : Thanks, that definitely gives some hope.

Comment: @PopularDemand - Aren't CSS files almost _required_ to be "open source", since they have to be sent for browsers to read them? Also, I'm not sure I would really consider them "source", since they are just formatting definitions. More like a textual graphic design format, which I suppose makes them...art?

Comment: @cdeszaq In a sense, yes, but as the OP pointed out, some of the content he's looking for may not be available in minified format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Jeremy Banks [guessed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126135/where-can-i-find-the-original-css-files-of-stackoverflow#comment341344_126135), the CSS is actually written in [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). The LESS source script is available at http://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflow/all.less. This is SO-specific; the other sites are available in other content folders (for example, [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)'s CSS is at http://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/unix/all.less)

Comment: These links are redirecting me to the login page (though the JavaScript files are still available). Do they still work for you, or has something changed since you made this post?

Comment: Weird, they work when I try [through coral cache](http://dev.stackoverflow.com.nyud.net/content/stackoverflow/all.less). In spite of the filename, those don't look like LESS to me. I think that's the LESS compiled as CSS, just pre-minification.

Comment: @JeremyBanks It doesn't work if I'm logged out (I go to the login page), but if I'm logged in it works fine. It does look like that's just plain CSS (although I suppose that's also legal LESS); I'm not sure why

Comment: @MichaelMrozek You (as a moderator?) have access to the `dev.` site? I get bounced when I try to log in.

Comment: @JeremyBanks No, sorry; I meant I needed to login to the regular Stack Overflow and then it worked, although now that I try again it appears to work even when I'm logged out of everything. Maybe it was a fluke? Does it work for you now?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek It doesn't. Logged in or logged out of the parent site, I still get the login page on `dev.`.

Comment: @JeremyBanks It works for me on some computers, doesn't work on others. I have no idea why, they all resolve to the same IP

Comment: Endless login loop detected, abort, retry, login?

Comment: Does this include the handheld Less / CSS?  I'm trying to configure a wiki with a new skin that is nicer looking for handhelds like what SO has.  Mine currently looks horrible on my BlackBerry Curve 9330..

Comment: Broken link, I suppose.